# Displaying mosaic dataset footprints with ArcGIS Image Service

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, mosaic, footprint, image-service

Is there a way to display the footprints created through a mosaic dataset with an Image Service?

I have a mosaic dataset that created footprints with associated data that can be viewed in ArcCatalog. However, when shared as an image service, only the image is displayed.  You can open properties and make the footprints viewable, but this doesn't show up in the table of contents for selection or detailed functions/processes.

Does anyone know how to make the footprints a selectable layer in an Image Service, or is this the wrong way to go about doing this?